# Ungroup Address Field in SugarCRM

Tags: php, templates, customization, sugarcrm

I need to remove 'City' from the Address template but keep the option of copying the Billing Address. How can I edit the way the Address is grouped?

Comment: Did the answer I provided solve your issue? @user2506329

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the change globally in an upgrade-safe manner you can copy the templates (if your locale is set to 'en_us') from:

```
include/SugarFields/Fields/Address/en_us.DetailView.tpl
include/SugarFields/Fields/Address/en_us.EditView.tpl
```

and save them to:

```
custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/Address/en_us.DetailView.tpl
custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/Address/en_us.EditView.tpl
```

Then inside the custom .tpl files remove the field(s) or make any other customization you'd like. If this is on a per module basis then you'd have to do a little more work.